# Changing from Slug to Id to post an item

Tags: python, django

I am trying to change from Slug to Id related to an item in order to fix a bug related to quantity in my project.

So I have switched everything from slug to id but i keep getting `Page not found (404) No Item matches the given query.`

I have updated the Models functions, View, URLs and template related to the order summary, I am not sure if there something else I need to update

Here are my models which I started with:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })

    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:remove-from-cart", kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })
```

Here are my urls:

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
    path('add-to-cart/<id>/', add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),
    path('remove-item-from-cart/<id>/', remove_single_item_from_cart,
         name='remove-single-item-from-cart'),
    path('remove-from-cart/<id>/', remove_from_cart, name='remove-from-cart'),
```

Here are the views:

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=id)
    order_item_qs = OrderItem.objects.filter(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    item_var = []  # item variation
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for items in request.POST:
            key = items
            val = request.POST[key]
            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(
                    item=item,
                    category__iexact=key,
                    title__iexact=val
                )
                item_var.append(v)
            except:
                pass

        if len(item_var) > 0:
            for items in item_var:
                order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
                    variation__exact=items,
                )

    if order_item_qs.exists():
        order_item = order_item_qs.first()
        order_item.quantity += 1
        order_item.save()
    else:
        order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
            item=item,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False
        )
        order_item.variation.add(*item_var)
        order_item.save()

    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if not order.items.filter(item__id=order_item.id).exists():
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to cart.")
        return redirect("core:order-summary")


@login_required
def remove_from_cart(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=id)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__id=item.id).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
            order.items.remove(order_item)
            order_item.delete()
            messages.info(request, "This item was removed from your cart")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")

        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart")
            return redirect("core:product", id=id)
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You don't have an active order")
        return redirect("core:product", id=id)


@login_required
def remove_single_item_from_cart(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=id)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__id=item.id).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
            if order_item.quantity > 1:
                order_item.quantity -= 1
                order_item.save()
            else:
                order.items.remove(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart")
            return redirect("core:product", id=id)
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order")
        return redirect("core:product", id=id)
```

Here are the template

```
<div class="pull-center">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'add-to-cart' order_item.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <a href="{% url 'remove-single-item-from-cart' order_item.id %}" class="btn mr-2"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
        {{ order_item.quantity }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn ml-2"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: forgot to change the slug here, `path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu  I actually kept it on purpose, I am only trying to change from slug ti id inorder to fix a bug related to add to cart and remove from cart.